# Return file download from byte[]

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, asp.net-mvc-4

This code

```
string xml = XmlHelper.ToXml(queryTemplate);

byte[] xmlb = StringHelper.GetBytes(xml);

var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    // for example foo.bak
    FileName = String.Format("{0}_v{1}.xml", queryModel.Name, queryModel.Version),

    // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want
    // the browser to try to show the file inline
    Inline = false,
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
return File(xmlb, "application/xml");
```

Turns out the string encoding is incorrect after it's converted into `byte[]`

So I need to put the `string` immediately into file, like this

```
FileStream xfile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(dldir, filename), FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
hssfwb.Write(xfile);
```

But I don't want to do this, I don't need the file after the download. I just need to return it to the browser as file download and don't want to have to deal with file deletion afterward which can become pretty hectic when there's a lot of request.

How to correct the character encoding from `string` to `byte[]` and correctly return it to the browser?

The `GetBytes` function looks like this

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: What is `StringHelper`, it makes no sense to call something like `GetBytes` on a string without specifying encoding

Comment: sorry for not including the GetBytes function, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the answer for this, it turns out the problem was character encoding.

The solution link is below

[Converting string to byte[] creates zero character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181866/converting-string-to-byte-creates-zero-character)

Answer (score 14):

Something like this would work:

```
try
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
    Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename ); 
    Response.OutputStream.Write(xmlb, 0, xmlb.Length); 
    Response.Flush(); 
} 
catch(Exception ex) 
{
    // An error occurred.. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

You will end up with UTF-16LE encoding, because that's what a `char` array is internally.

You should get rid of that function because it's both misleading and redundant duplication of functionality already existing out of the box because `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` already does the same thing: *An encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order*.

If creating a temporary file without specifying encoding works, then you probably want Windows-1252 because that was most likely being used implicitly when creating the file:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] xmlb = enc.GetBytes(xml);
```

If you wanted UTF-8 you would do:

```
byte[] xmlb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
```