# Converting string to byte[] creates zero character

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, byte

In this convert function

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

byte[] test = GetBytes("abc");
```

The resulting array contains zero character

```
test = [97, 0, 98, 0, 99, 0]
```

And when we convert byte[] back to string, the result is

```
string test = "a b c "
```

How do we make it so it doesn't create those zeroes

Comment: You created those zeroes seemingly on purpose when you copied chars into a byte array.. What sort of encoding *do* you want? ASCII? UTF-8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return file download from byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158804/return-file-download-from-byte)

Comment: ToCharArray, as the name says, returns char[]. A char is 16 bits, i.e. 2 bytes. So you get an additional byte with value 0 even for simple ASCII text.

Comment: @strike_noir Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's look at what your code does wrong. [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is 16-bit (2 byte) in .NET framework. Which means when you write `sizeof(char)`, it returns `2`. `str.Length` is `1`, so actually your code will be `byte[] bytes = new byte[2]` is the same `byte[2]`. So when you use [`Buffer.BlockCopy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) method, you actually copy `2` bytes from a source array to a destination array. Which means your `GetBytes()` method returns `bytes[0] = 32` and `bytes[1] = 0` if your string is `" "`.

Try to use [`Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) instead.

> When overridden in a derived class, encodes all the characters in the
>   specified string into a sequence of bytes.

```
const string input = "Soner Gonul";

byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

foreach ( byte element in array )
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", element, (char)element);
}
```

Output:

```
83 = S
111 = o
110 = n
101 = e
114 = r
32 =
71 = G
111 = o
110 = n
117 = u
108 = l
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear the confusion about your answer, char type in C# takes 2 bytes. So, string.toCharArray() returns an array in which each item takes 2 bytes of storage. While copying to byte array where each item takes 1 byte storage, there occurs a data loss. Hence the zeroes showing up in result.

 As suggested, `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` is a safer option to use.

Comment: There is no data loss, it is effectively doing the same as `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` which is encoding as UTF16 Little Endian.

Answer (score 1):

In reality .net (at least for 4.0) automatically changes size of char when serialized with BinaryWriter

UTF-8 chars have variable length (might not be 1 byte), ASCII chars have 1 byte

'ē' = 2 bytes

'e' = 1 byte

It must be kept in mind when using

```
BinaryReader.ReadChars(stream)
```

In case of word "ēvalds" = 7 bytes  size will be different than "evalds" = 6 bytes

Comment: "UTF-8 chars have 2 bytes"... What?  UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `Encoding` explicitly. You can use next code to convert string to bytes with specified encoding

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc");
```

if you print contents of bytes, you will get `{ 97, 
98, 
99 }` which doesn't contain zeros, as in your example
In your example default encoding using 16 bits per symbol. It can be observer by printing the results of

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("abc"); // { 97, 0, 98, 0, 99, 0 }
```

Then while converting it back, you should select the appropriate encoding:

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine (str);
```

Prints `"abc"` as you might expected

Comment: Or use the Unicode Encoding to convert back from what he got from GetBytes: `string str = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);` Then it should work with non-Ascii as well. Still you should always specify the encoding going either way: `byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("abc");` Note that the default UnicodeEncoding is little endian, if you plan on doing networking and switching endianness or working with other languages than C#.

Answer (score 0):

(97,0) is Unicode representation of 'a'. Unicode represents each character in two bytes. So you can not remove zeros. But you can change Encoding to ASCII. Try following for Converting string to byte[].

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
```