# Saving Stream to response object

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I’m using a web API and this includes a method to get a file from within the system.  Here is a code snippet it provides

```
    System.IO.Stream s = new System.IO.FileStream(
    @"c:\File.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
result = proxy.get_doc_file(fileId, ref s );
s.Close();
```

Now what I like to do is to convert this stream so that the file is available to download.  I believe this is done by using a response object?  Basically I’d like the user to get ‘save as’ dialog box.

Any help much appreciated.  I’m using C# .net 3.5

Comment: you can find it right here by searching a bit - [here is an example question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: It sounds like you're right on track.  You simply need to build the middle layer (your code above) which is responsible pulling back the result from the proxy, wrapping it in a http response object, and returning it to the client.  Check out -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158804/return-file-download-from-byte